# Most performant way to delete all NamedItems of a Worksheet?

Tags: excel, performance, office-js

Any suggenstions to improve performance when deleting all NamedItems of a Worksheet?
I cannot delete the Worksheet entirely because I want to keep the underlying formats.
The following approach is pretty slow ...

```
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const app = context.workbook.application;
            const sheet: Excel.Worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItemOrNullObject(`${sheetName}`);
            await context.sync();
            if (!sheet.isNullObject) {
                const namedItems: Excel.NamedItemCollection = sheet.names.load('name');
                await context.sync();
                app.suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync();
                sheet.names.items.forEach(ni => ni.delete());
            }});
```

Comment: How many named items are there, and how long does it take? Also, are you using getItemOfNullObject because there's a chance that the sheet won't exist?

Comment: There were arround 400. I've reduced them to 80 and now it takes arround 1200 ms to delete them. (Roughly the same tme to write them).
The worksheet will be created, if it doesn't already exist.  (You can't see that in the example code)
The runtime here is still IE11 (corporate context)

Comment: If the worksheet is guaranteed to exist, then use `getItem` instead of `getItemOrNullObject`. This will enable you to delete the first `context.sync` (which will save you one roundtrip from the add-in to the document) and you can also eliminate the check of `sheet.isNullObject`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I my case I need the extra roundtrip - if the worksheet doesn't exist I'll create it. I guess I'll have to wait until there's a DeleteAll() function on the Excel.NamedItemCollection

Comment: For new API ask, please go to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions) and see if your feature has already been requested or request a new feature.